# How to avoid ksh to save a password from command line?

Tags: shell, ksh

I have coded a script in `ksh` which receives a password as parameter in the command line, like:
`myscript.sh -u myid -p mypwd`

The problem is that this script is used with an service id, which anyone in the team can use, and in this way, the password will be saved in the ksh command history, and that can be a concern in audit.

Also, if someone do a `ps -ef|grep myscript` during the execution, he/she will be able to catch the password provided in the command line

My main goal here is have a way to call the script but somehow not have the password saved on the history, and if possible, avoid to have it also on the `ps -ef` output

I know how to disable the history entirely, but I CAN'T do it, as the history might be available for audit reasons.

`bash` is not an option at this moment.
I can edit the script itself, but I don't have root auth on the server.

This script is called together with others, multiple times (sometimes, +100 times) so, get this from STDIN on each interaction would not work.

Does anyone see  a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the script to read the password from STDIN rather than as a command line argument? You can use the shell builtin 'read' to do this.

Comment: sorry @abasterfield , I didn't mention, but that is not an option either. This script is called by another script in a loop, +100 times ... then I can't keep typing the pwd everytime. I will update the question to clarify this point

Answer (score 0):

Store the password in a readable-by-user only file. Have the script:

1. accept the file name from the command line (and default to something reasonable, say `$HOME/.script_secret`),
2. (optionally) ensure that the file is user-only readable, then
3. read the secret from the file.